# Align product buttons in WooCommerne

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce on the Flatsome Wordpress theme. I need to align the orange buttons on the following page : [My Website](https://mimsi.dk/)

The buttons should always align on a horizontal line. I tried to solve the problem with this code in my custom CSS, but nothing is happening at all. To make sure I could write some custom CSS at all I tried to change the background on the buttons. That is working fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    min-height: 500px !important;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
ul.products li.product a.button {
    position: absolute !important; 
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: What is the `horizontal line` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove these styles:

```
a.button.add_to_cart_button,
a.button.product_type_simple {
    /* bottom: 30px; */
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

This should make buttons nicely aligned.

**Upd:**

```
a.button.add_to_cart_button,
a.button.product_type_simple {
    bottom: auto !important;
    position: static !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just looked in the style.css through ftp and through the editor in Wordpress. The style.css is totally empty. That is weird?

Comment: @McDuck4 Have you checked custom styles via "Flatsome > Advanced > Custom CSS"? These are custom styles, and they are applied via internal `style` tags embedded into the page - this is definitely not default Flatsome Theme styles.

Comment: @McDuck4 - please check the update of this post. That's needed to give you code some priority

Comment: these styles may be added by some wordpress plugin. Try to find them in your code: download whole "plugins" and "themes" folders with ftp on your local machine and search for "a.button.product_type_simple" code inside

Comment: Thank you alot for your answer. I just tried to add your suggestion: https://ibb.co/mPMZ7b . and updated the site. But still the same. That is weird. I am taking over the site from another one, so I do not know the setup at all :-/

Comment: @McDuck4 take a look at your website now, it's far better than it was

Comment: On my screen it is exact the same. I also tried in Inkognito window, and they are not aligning. Weird... When I am on a small screen they align ok. But on my desktop screen they are not aligning.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h69r0k - here is the screenshot. have you dropped the browser cache?

Comment: I just tried a pc. They are aligning very nice there.I just made 3 of my friends try to go on the site. They are not aligning there. They are using a pc. My girlfriends computer it is looking nice on. 

So it can have something to do with screen size?

Comment: I can see it has something to do with the breakpoints. When I hit the 697px breakpoint the buttons start jumping up and down.